# Eloquent query builder - where is that 'is null' coming from?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

This is the query:

```
$allTests = \DB::connection('tars-test')
->table('tars-test.uut_result')
->select(\DB::raw('max(`START_DATE_TIME`)'))
->from('uut_result')
->where(\DB::raw("date(`START_DATE_TIME`) = '$date'"))
->where('uut_serial_number', $test->UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER)
->toSql();
```

This is the output:

```
"select max(`START_DATE_TIME`) from `uut_result` where 
date(`START_DATE_TIME`) = '2016-08-09' is null and `uut_serial_number` = ?"
```

Where is that "is null" coming from?

Comment: is `$date` null? or in wrong format

Answer (score 0):

there's no second parameter on this line:

```
->where(\DB::raw("date(`START_DATE_TIME`) = '$date'"))
```

break it down to:

```
->where(\DB::raw('date(`START_DATE_TIME`)'), $date)
```

and it works

Comment: you could also use the whereRaw() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
->where(\DB::raw("date(`START_DATE_TIME`) = '$date'"))
```

change where to ->whereRaw

```
->whereRaw(\DB::raw("date(`START_DATE_TIME`) = '$date'"))
```